# Angular 2+ modal popup timer and redirect

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, modal-dialog

I want to make a request on mongodb and while the request is loading I want a modal windows popup with a hourglass who leave when the request is ending and redirect on an other route if possible.

Angular 2+
NodeJS
MongoDB

I have the modal windows popup ready.

Edit : Easy way
I found by adding a "dialogRef.close() in the res"

```
        this.countModelService.getCount(datas)
        .subscribe(res =>
        {
            dialogRef.close();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more `angular` related than `node.js` ... Imagine you have your mongoDB request implemented as an angular service `mongoService`.  Imagine, your popup is done with ng-bootstrap - `NgbModal`. Then the client side code could look like this:

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MongoService } from './services/mongo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomp',
  templateUrl: './mycomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomp.component.scss']
})
export class MycompComponent implements OnInit, ... {

    mr: NgbModalRef;

    constructor(...
        private mongo: MongoService,
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        ...) {
        }

    ngOnInit() {
        // some initialization ...
    }

    getFromDB() {       // <--- this is the function you call when clicking your button

        this.mr = this.modalService.open(content);
        mongo.getData().subscribe(
            data => {
                // ... your data handling ...
                this.mr.close();
                this.router.navigate(['/anotherroute']);

            },
            error => {
                // ... your error handling ...
                this.mr.close();
            }
        )
    }
}
```

CSS-Styling with hourglass should then be something like

```
...
cursor: wait;
...
```